# Text not showing when sending html gmail using python

Tags: python, gmail

Im trying to send gmail email using python. The email includes plain text and an html image to be shown in the email. However when i try sending the email, the text is not showing  (only image is shown).

Below is the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart  import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

host='smtp.gmail.com'
port=587
username='sender@gmail.com'
password='mypassword'
from_email=username
to_list=['recipient@gmail.com']

email_conn=smtplib.SMTP(host,port)
email_conn.ehlo()
email_conn.starttls()
email_conn.login(username,password)



msg=MIMEMultipart('Alternative')
temp=MIMEMultipart('Alternative2')

msg['Subject']='Hello'
msg['From']=username



txt='Welcome home'

part1=MIMEText(txt,'plain')




msgText = MIMEText('<img src="cid:image1">', 'html')
temp.attach(msgText)


fp = open('/home/user/Pictures/image.jpg', 'rb')
msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()

# Define the image's ID as referenced above
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
temp.attach(msgImage)


msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(temp)


email_conn.sendmail(from_email,to_list,msg.as_string())
email_conn.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate error is that you are creating a invalid MIME part with type `multipart/Alternative2`.  You seem to be confusing the *type* (which should be one out of a limited set of IANA-approved labels) with a unique identifier.

More fundamentally, you seem to be following some obsolete `email` guideline.  The proper way to create a new message in Python 3.6+ is to use the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API.

Also, you will want to restructure your code so that the message creation is not mixed with the message sending.  In the following, I have simply removed all the `smtplib` code; this also makes it easy for you to troubleshoot locally with `print(msg.as_string())` instead of sending the message.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid


username = 'sender@gmail.com'
to_list = ['recipient@gmail.com']

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Hello'
msg['From'] = username
# Need recipient!
msg['To'] = ', '.join(to_list)

msg.set_content('Welcome home')

image_id = make_msgid()

# Notice closing slash at the end of <img ... />
msg.add_alternative('<img src="%s" />' % image_id.strip('<>'), subtype='html')

with open('/home/user/Pictures/image.jpg', 'rb') as fp:
    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(
        fp.read(), 'image', 'jpeg', cid=image_id)
```

This rather closely follows the "asparagus" example from the [`email` examples in the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

You would then go on to create an SMTP session and `smtp.send_message(msg)` rather than take the detour to separately and explicitly convert the message to a string you can pass to the legacy `sendmail` method; this is one of the many improvements in the new API.